# Bash: Replace "nothing" with zero

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I get as output "nothing", and I need to replace that with "0". For instance, my file has `duse` as follows:

```
duse     1
```

and `awk` prints `1` with:

```
surange < survey.su | grep duse | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Because there is no `delrt`, the code gives no result for that variable:

```
surange < survey.su | grep delrt | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

because `delrt` does not exist.

Just to add that redirecting the output to a file:

```
surange < survey.su | grep delrt | awk '{ print $2 }' > value
```

says `empty` after using `file`:

```
$ file value 
value: empty
```

Any idea? thanks for any pointers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is not outputting anything, so the `awk` expressions never run.  A manual check can be added in the `END` block.

```
surange < survey.su | grep delrt | awk '{print$2}END{if(NR==0)print 0}'
```

The `if(NR==0)` part checks if no records have been read (an empty file), and responds accordingly.

Alternatively the whole thing can be done in `awk`, setting a flag if a match is found.

```
surange < survey.su | awk '/delrt/{print$2;f=1}END{if(!f)print 0}'
```

Comment: thanks kdhp, I also thought about that but it doesn't print anything

Comment: now it works, thanks a lot kdhp, nice trick. It'd be great an explanation about your solution. Using only `awk` didn't work.